# How can I avoid an If/Then Statement From Checking its "IF"

Tags: c#, if-statement, for-loop

I was wondering if anyone Knows how I can avoid re-running the If Statement in the following code

```
int x = 1;
load_page(standurl, 0);
firstentryOnload = UrlList[0];
for (int i = 1; i <= lastPage; i++)
{
    if (UrlList.Count > setting_EPP) table_populate(0);
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(delay);
    load_page(standurl, i);
    if (x > 10)
    {
        //refresh firstpage,check for new data
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(delay);
        x = 1;
    }
    x++;
}
```

I want to run table_populate(0); when the UrlList.Count > setting_EPP
Without the "If/Then" checking Every Loop.

Essentially I want it to run that If Statement once and then stop existing.

*I know how to stop the if/then statement from running, But I don't want it to keep checking after it runs*

Edit: The Loop runs in the background and currently takes about 4 hours to run to completion. I have been trying to find some way to put this outside the loop, however I am not having much luck. The only thing I can think of is Running Another thread alongside the one running the above code, that runs the If statement every few moments?

Comment: Can't you just get the logic out of the loop?

Comment: Move the `if` statement outside the loop? `if (UrlList.Count > setting_EPP) table_populate(0); for (int i = 0....)`

Comment: I have been trying to figure out how I can bring it out of the loop but this runs in a background thread. So Id have to time it? Or maybe I can create an event that only fires once? but I believe that would just lead me to a different if statement. 

The code runs Forever Till the program closes or it reaches the last page (about 11200 which at 1 page per about 1.3seconds(approximately 4 hours)

Comment: If you have other conditions that you've not included in your question, [edit] your question so that they're available to us, so we're not wasting our time trying to help you with incomplete information.

Comment: System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(x++ % 10 ? 0 : delay); ?

Comment: @Dmitri Sosnik Sorry Im refering to the Other If statement, although I do like that statement :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can wrap condition in delegate and replace delegate when condition is met:

```
 Action check;
 check = ()=> { 
     if (UrlList.Count > setting_EPP) 
     {
        table_populate(0);
        check = () => {}; // replace check with no-op.
     }
   };
 ....
 for(...)
 {
    check();
    ...
 }
```

<sub>This code is written by trained professionals on closed course, don't try at home (or any non-self-education code). :)</sub>

More traditional pattern - have flag that says "condition met, don't check anymore" - but indeed it will require `if` statement.

Note: if this code checks shared date you need to either use `lock` or other synchronization methods (i.e. one of concurrent collections).

Comment: Thanks, and the only data that is shared is the UrlList but its only written to in this loop. (Should I still use Lock?) PS: Thats really clever I Never would have thought to replace a delegate with a no-op

Comment: @JasonBrown if UrlList can be read/updated from any other thread you need locking/synchronization. You may want to show more complete sample that actually demonstrates whey "UrlList" changes - if it grows inside the loop simple `isTablePopulated` flag updated when you call the method would be most readable solution.

Comment: For the syntax to be correct I had to change `check = () => {};` to `check = delegate{};` not sure but are these 2 statements the same?

Comment: @JasonBrown sounds like you're using an older version of .Net / Visual Studio.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn Im running VS2013 community edition, building for .net 4.5

Comment: ...well I have a lot of Lock's to do now... Time to go learn more about threading :) least my programs not insanely complicated yet

Answer (score 3):

I'll start by noting that both sides of your conditional expression appear to be unaffected by the body of the loop; that is, both `UrlList.Count` and `setting_EPP` appear not to change during the body of the loop. It's possible that the `load_page()` or `table_populate()` functions change something, or that another thread changes something, but for now I'll assume that this is true, as the question doesn't seem to make much sense otherwise (I promise: the conditional check is **NOT** a significant or measurable factor of your performance).

Given that, the question is still not clear, but I have it down to two possibilities. One is that you just need to load the table at the beginning of the loop. That's easy; just call it before entering the loop body:

```
int x = 1;
load_page(standurl, 0);
firstentryOnload = UrlList[0];
if (UrlList.Count > setting_EPP) table_populate(0);
for (int i = 1; i <= lastPage; i++)
{

    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(delay);
    load_page(standurl, i);
    if (x > 10)
    {
        //refresh firstpage,check for new data
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(delay);
        x = 1;
    }
    x++;
}
```

The other possibility is that you want to run this on every iteration if the condition is met, but just want to avoid checking the condition over and over. In that case, you could wrap the whole thing in a single `if()` block:

```
int x = 1;
load_page(standurl, 0);
firstentryOnload = UrlList[0];
if (UrlList.Count > setting_EPP) 
{
    for (int i = 1; i <= lastPage; i++)
    {
        table_populate(0);
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(delay);
        load_page(standurl, i);
        if (x > 10)
        {
            //refresh firstpage,check for new data
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(delay);
            x = 1;
        }
        x++;
    }
}
else
{
    for (int i = 1; i <= lastPage; i++)
    {
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(delay);
        load_page(standurl, i);
        if (x > 10)
        {
            //refresh firstpage,check for new data
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(delay);
            x = 1;
        }
        x++;
    }
}
```

And, of course, you could abstract out most of the repeated code to a separate method.

Actually, there is a third possibility. I could be wrong, and something changes `UrlList` or `setting_EPP` during the loop, and you just want to run this the first time the condition becomes true, without needing to make the check on every iteration. In that case, you can do something like this:

```
int i = 1;
while (i <= lastPage && UrlList.Count <= setting_EPP)
{
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(delay);
    load_page(standurl, i);
    if (i % 10 == 0) System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(delay);
    i++;
}
if (i <= lastPage && UrlList.Count > setting_EPP) table_populate(0);
while (i <= lastPage)
{
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(delay);
    load_page(standurl, i);
    if (i % 10 == 0) System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(delay);
    i++;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the response, however I am not able to run the if before the loop since the Load_page is what populates UrlList and its a user setting that controls the setting_EPP (well it will be haven't actually converted it to a setting yet, just preparing) Although I know it wouldn't cause much lag just having 1 or 2 if statements, but it seem wasteful to do a check every single loop, when you only need it to run the first time it succeeds.

Comment: If `load_page()` is what populated UrlList, I would make two design changes to your code. The first is to have `load_page()` return the loaded data (your UrlList). The second would be to make `load_page()` responsible for populating the table.

Comment: I had it running like that but I'm trying to break up the code a bit more so the functions are a bit more "functional", (Before It was calling a chain of 6 or so methods)

Comment: Chaining function calls: A().B().C()... _is_ the functional programming way.

Comment: The only issue with that is, I have user input changing whats populated to the table, while the load_page() continues scraping till program ends. so if load_page populated the table, I would have to change the way table is populated (currently it stores all the data scraped in memory and then displays locally calculated "pages") or list every entry in 1 table (which would result in a rowcount of estimated 2.5million). Essentially that "if" statement is me avoiding creating events which I'm still having trouble wrapping my head around